# How do I get rid of right click context menu

Tags: rendering

I was in blender and I was just trying to make a render but I cant right click select. Instead of selecting with right click, a stupid context menu pops up. I need help

Answer (score 1):

In `Edit > Preferences > Keymap`, you can change the 'select with' parameter to right. Left click will automatically change to Cursor. This used to be the default behaviour till version 2.79[image: Blender Preferences]